# how to achieve drill down functionality in asp.net mvc project using asp.net chart control

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, drilldown, microsoft-chart-controls

I have created a chart in asp.net mvc project..
Controller looks like:

```
 public ActionResult ApplicationPieChart()

    {   
        var _context = new chart();
        ArrayList xValue = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList yValue = new ArrayList();

   var a = (from c in _context.vw_AppType select c);
        var b = a.GroupBy(x => x.ApplicationName, (k, cnt) => new { ApplicationName = k, cnt = cnt.Count() });
        b.ToList().ForEach(rs => xValue.Add(rs.ApplicationName));
        b.ToList().ForEach(rs => yValue.Add(rs.cnt));

 new Chart(width: 500, height: 300, theme: ChartTheme.Blue)
            .AddTitle("Count Of Application")
            .AddSeries("Default",chartArea:null, chartType: "pie", xValue: xValue, yValues: yValue)
            .AddLegend()
            .Write("bmp");

        return null;
    }
```

and the view part is:

```
    <table>
          <tr>
             <td>
          <img src="@Url.Action("ApplicationPieChart")" />
             </td>       
          </tr>
    </table>
```

I got the chart now I need to implement drill down functionality in my chart and i need to show the values and percentage in the chart.. How can I achieve them.

Comment: Please add some more code of what you already tried to achieve your desired behaviour. Also a more detailed description of what youre in search of would be helpful to answer your question.

Comment: this code is giving me a simple pie chart, but I am not able to add any values or percentage with chart